# get checked input value to array

Tags: jquery

how to i can get all checked input values to array?

i can get all checked inputs but cant to get values.

**jQuery:**

```
$("[id^='generate_']").click(function() {

    val=$(this).closest('tr').find("#cnt").text();  

    var obj = $("#testSlide_"+val).find(':checkbox');
    var childCount = obj.size();
    var checkedCount =  obj.filter(':checked').length;  

        var checkValues = [];
        $(childCount).each(function() {
             alert($(this).val());
        checkValues.push($(this)val());
});

});
```

i want to use ajax and send to serverside and use foreach .

Comment: This is what you are looking for http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: what data you want to sent to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to return a new jQuery object containing the return values of a function:

```
var values = $("#testSlide_"+val).find(':checkbox:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

The call to [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) is there to convert the jQuery object into a native array.